# How do I use data from one spreadsheet to fill in similar fields in another spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Every month I have to generate a roster of several hundred employees, which includes contact information, duty station, rank, etc. My task is to fill in any blank cells with the relevant details, which I can either find from last month's spreadsheet or the internet database. The rosters don't vary much from month to month. How can I populate the new roster with information from the old roster? For example, if I have A1: `John Smith`, B1: `(123)-456-789` in last month's roster and A1: `John Smith`, B1: `n/a` in this month's roster, is there a way to automatically find John Smith's number in last month's spreadsheet and have it appear in this month's spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the formula for `vlookup`.

In cell B1 in the new sheet, you do:

`=vlookup(A1, PreviousmonthSheet!A:B, 2, false)`

`vlookup` basically finds the corresponding value in the sheet you select (in this case, the previous month sheet) and returns the value next to some index (in this case, `John Smith`).

In this case, it takes 'John Smith', looks it up in the sheet `PreviousmonthSheet` in column A, and returns the value that is in column B (second column from column A, hence the `2` there). False means exact match, you would most likely want to use this.

The formula is:

`=vlookup(lookup_value, tablearray, column_index_no, [range_lookup])`

EDIT: In case it's another workbook, you will need to insert the workbook name in the `tablearray` part like this:

`=vlookup(A1, [Workbookname.xlsx]PreviousmonthSheet!A:B, 2, false)`

Comment: Oh no, I did mean A1, B1. My bad.

Comment: Terminology Check: This example is accessing another *Worksheet* ("Sheet"), and not another Workbook ("Spreadsheet").

Comment: Thank you @Jerry and RBarryYoung. If, for example, John Smith is in A15 in last month's workbook and in A1 in this month's workbook, is there a way to fill in the corresponding phone number into this month's workbook?

Comment: @user2031026: Yes, you need to change the formula so it becomes `=vlookup(A15, PreviousmonthSheet!A:B, 2, false)`. Did you see what I changed?

Comment: Oh, so you remove the lookup_value and it will search the whole workbook? @Jerry

Comment: @Jerry, I see what you changed- A15. The issue is that I have multiple blank cells to fill, and rather than addressing each one individually, I would like to be able to fill all the blank cells with a formula that would refer back to last month's spreadsheet. Usually I don't know exactly what cell John Smith is in-- I realize I can ctrl+F, but then I might as well just copy-paste the phone numbers individually. Thanks!

Comment: @user2031026 You can just put the formula (the one in my answer, not the one in my above comment) in cell B1 and fill it down (using the little black square at the lower right corner of the selected cell, or selecting all the cells to get the formula and pressing `Ctrl`+`D`). The formula should adjust itself automatically!